# Android: How to get the url of the website downloading my apk file?

Tags: android

Here is the scenario.

I want to deploy my app on some forums with apk file. In this case, I want to get a statistic datas that show me ""How many times the app being downloaded in certain forum.""

So here is my idea, I want to get the download url when the user download the apk file. By analysing the url, I can know exactly which forum the user downloaded the apk file.

Is there any way to do it in the app? Any kind of advice is appreciated~~~

Comment: Just put it on Google play and you'll get all the stats you want ;)

Comment: Use Google analytics

Comment: I want to put my app on both Google play and other forums. I know Google analytics can handle that for the case of Google Play. But I still not sure how to do it when i publish on the forums.